# How to generate Hyperlink in stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, hyperlink

I tried to generate a hyperlink using a stored procedure. But I couldn't build my link. But I used this link from my  code in C# it's working. Here is my link.

Code behind:

```
" + "<a target = '_self' href='http://" + mailResponsePath + "/MailResponseAuthorization.aspx?UserID=" + user.UserID.ToString() + "&ABMonth=" + ab.ActivityStartDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") + "&Action=0'>Click Here.</a>
```

Stored procedure:

```
<a href=http://145.17.58.35/MailResponseAuthorization.aspx?UserID='+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@UserId) +'&ABMonth=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) +'&Action=0>Click Here.</a>
```

Comment: Besides typos...please reconsider to generate UI _things_ inside your stored procedures. There are debates about storing domain logic in SP and you're putting there HTML generation (not to mention that you're not doing any escaping then it may be even broken). It's a **NO-NO** (maximum emphasis)

Answer (score 0):

I see that the apostrophes for href is missing
if you are trying to build the whole  tag in SP, try this:

```
DECLARE @a nvarchar(500)
SET @a = '<a href="http://145.17.58.35/MailResponseAuthorization.aspx?UserID='+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@UserId) +'&ABMonth=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) +'&Action=0">click here.</a>'
```